# How to change font in RMarkdown when using "rticles" package?

Tags: r, latex, yaml, r-markdown

I recently installed the "rticles" package in R to automatically set up a journal article template in RMarkdown. I've been pretty impressed with it so far, but I'd like to be able to change the font. Surely this is possible somehow, but I have been unable to find any online resource explaining how to do it.

I am interested in knitting to PDF.

Here is the YAML at the top of my RMarkdown script:

```
---
title: This title
author:
  - name: This author
    email: t.author@thisPlace.com
    affiliation: This institute
address:
  - code: This institute
    address: Street, City, State, etc.
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
keywords: "fun, happiness"
journal: "This Elsevier Journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rticles::elsevier_article
---
```

I generated this by running the following line of code in R:

```
rmarkdown::draft("Test.Rmd", template = "elsevier_article", package = "rticles")
```

So where in all of this can I control font? Before using "rticles" I used to change the font by changing the latex engine and then specifying the font as follows:

```
---
title: This title
author: "This author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    fig_caption: TRUE
    df_print: kable
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri Light
---
```

Is it possible to do something analogous to this in "rticles"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you control fonts is analogous to what you did before:

```
---
title: This title
author:
  - name: This author
    email: t.author@thisPlace.com
    affiliation: This institute
address:
  - code: This institute
    address: Street, City, State, etc.
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.

  It consists of two paragraphs.
keywords: "fun, happiness"
journal: "This Elsevier Journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Calibri Light        
---
```

Comment: Thanks! If I am permitted a follow up question--where can I find a list of fonts that I could use in the code above?

Comment: @ben The beauty with XeLaTeX is that you can use any TTF/OTF font that is installed in your system. For example Calibri (Light) comes with Windows or Office but is still usable from XeLaTeX. On some systems you can list the installed fonts with `fc-list : family` on the command line.